# How to auto-resize UITableViewCell when I want to add text dynamic

Tags: ios, swift

I'm setting up a UITableView with few cells. When I hold on a cell then a menu will show up and I can add a comment/text into my cell.
What I want is to don't show the white space of the comment labels if the user don't insert any comment. But if the user insert a comment then that label to show up and to display the whole comment inserted.
Is this possible to do this without to hardcode the height of the cell ? Because this app will run on multiple devices and the screen is different to each one.

I already tried unsuccessfully to use auto-layout using this lines of code in viewDidLoad:

```
questionsTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
questionsTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 390
```

Also I've tried to use `questionsTableView.beginUpdates` before to add the comment on label and `questionsTableView.endUpdates` after the comment was assigned to label but also is not working.

I can't manage to display the cell like this when the user run the app and if the user add any comment then to expand the cell and to display the label:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
class MainVC: UIViewController {

    // Interface Links
    @IBOutlet weak var questionsTableView: UITableView!

    // Properties
    var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!
    var firstCommentReceived = ""
    var secondCommentReceived = ""
    var images = [UIImage]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        questionsTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        questionsTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 390
    }
}

extension MainVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! MainCell
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.configCell()
        if !firstCommentReceived.isEmpty{
            cell.firstCommentLabel.text = firstCommentReceived
        }
        if !secondCommentReceived.isEmpty{
            cell.secondCommentLabel.text = secondCommentReceived
        }
        if !images.isEmpty{
            cell.selectedImageView.image = images[0]
        }
        return cell
    }

    // Set the height of each row from UITableView
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return 390 // size of the maximum height of the cell if the user add comments and images. This size should be dynamic not hardcoded.
    }
}
```

Here I've created a GitHub small example with my issue:
https://github.com/tygruletz/sendDataFromCellToController

Thank you if you are reading this !

Comment: Created pull request to your repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I look up on your project and I found that you have layout issues ^^"

1- You need to set the cell layout to be from the top to bottom layout and I see that you miss doing this to the last element in the cell which is the image

[image]

2- You need to find the dynamic labels that you are to use for example in yours It was the comment 1 and 2 which have the priority.

[image]
[image]

3- Finally I found that you make the cell height for static and in your case it should be dynamic

// Set the height of each row from UITableView

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension // in your app it was 390
}
```

if you want take look this is edit for the project code

https://ufile.io/plddi

Good luck ;)

Comment: And how can I remove this space when the app is running ?
https://imgur.com/DFXYoJ1

Comment: hmmm there's a lot of trick for doing this for example you can control with the constant for the height for each comment or the correct way is to use others nib cell :D

Comment: I set the height for label to 24pixels because I was getting warnings in console. If I remove the height for labels then is working but I have a lot of warnings. Here are the warnings: https://imgur.com/a/G3mVNsV

Comment: give me some time I will fix this for you and share screen for that

Comment: You want it like this right ? - https://imgur.com/a/c8zTzDJ - you can download the project and accept the answer if it's done for you (https://ufile.io/wz1om)

Comment: Amazing. I just learned that I can link constraints from view into my code and to manipulate the value from there. This is so awesome ! Thank you so much Ahmed !

Comment: <3 No problems any time <3

Answer (score 1):

Just give bottom constraint of your bottom imageView as you see in screenshot and set Height for row at with

```
return UITableView.automaticDimension
//or you can remove this method
```

[image]

Comment: And is possible to remove this space when I don't have anything in that label ?
https://imgur.com/DFXYoJ1
I set the height for label to 24pixels because I was getting warnings in console. If I remove the height for labels then I working but I have a lot of warnings.
Here are the warnings: https://imgur.com/ka5mkKR

Comment: I think just leave them empty. Tableview cell automatically set height

Comment: if i'm not wrong you want this? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cCI7_IEpfFgqvnCKbKOgH4DZKXcXRgNt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes. Also that UIImageView to won't be there if the user don't take a photo with camera. If the user Add a Comment / Tag / Photo then to show that Labels/ImageView.

Comment: okay. i have just remove your fixed text from labels. You need to make height constraint IBoutlet and then set it with 0. when user will add any comment you have call back of your alert set constraint with any height you want.

Comment: okay. i have just remove your fixed text from labels. You need to make height constraint IBoutlet in your cell class and then set it with 0. when user will add any comment you have call back just reload your tableview and check if comment string variable is not empty alert set constraint with any height you want.